# Read/write a file with credentials

Tags: java

I am trying to expose to users parts of a configuration file to have them change the status of a flag(s) at will. The file is on a VM in the network and user access a simple web app with a toggle buttons to change the status of the flags in the file.
The only way I was able to achieve this so far was to have the Tomcat instance run with a user that has access to the VM and the path given to the read/write algorithm is something similar to:

```
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("\\<VM_ADDRESS>\D$\path\to\file"));
```

Users login to the web app using Active Directory credentials and I would like to manage access to the file based on those AD user groups.

I there a way to read the content of a file using a different user? How can you supply credentials to the READ/WRITE process to comply with windows permissions in java code?